# ViewPager Save views in Fragments

Tags: android, save, android-viewpager, fragment, savestate

I am developing a launcher. I have a viewpager and when I add shortcuts on my fragment when I swiped the shortcut was dissappearing. I found a temporary solution by adding this

```
homePager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); //homePager==ViewPager (3)==my pages
```

But then I force closed the app and my shortcuts was dissappeared again. So my question is how can I save the fragment-page permanetly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite or preferences.